# Change of child widget colour on focus at Parent widget - Android

Tags: android, selector, parent-child, background-color, onfocus

I have a listview with three textviews embedded in it.
On focus at listview the requirement is to change the colour of listview from white to red.
And three textview to white from black.

Suggestion please,

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe you should try to use the [duplicateParentState](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#attr_android%3aduplicateParentState) attribute on TextViews?